# Modifying a member in a struct within a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, member

I am trying to solve a problem in an assignment I was given - the problem being is that one of the functions I am currently implementing does not work.

First and foremost, I was told that code provided by my professor (down below) cannot be modified in any way:

```
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 64
    typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE } BOOL;

typedef struct {
    char* fileName;         // Frame fileName
}Frame, *pFrame, **ppFrame;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int numFrames;     // number of Frame* 
    ppFrame frames;         // array of Frame*
}Animation, *pAnimation;

// Forward declarations
void initAnimation(pAnimation);
void insertFrame(pAnimation);
void deleteFrames(pAnimation);
void runFrames(pAnimation);

int main(void)
{
    char response;
    BOOL RUNNING = TRUE;
    Animation A;
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    initAnimation(&A);

    while (RUNNING)
    {
        printf("MENU\n 1. Insert a Frame\n 2. Delete all the Frames\n 3. Run the Animation\n 4. Quit\n");
        scanf("%c", &response);
        switch (response)
        {
        case '1':insertFrame(&A); break;
        case '2':deleteFrames(&A); break;
        case '3':runFrames(&A); break;
        case '4':RUNNING = FALSE; deleteFrames(&A); break;
            default:printf("Please enter a valid option\n");
        }
    printf("\n");
    while ((response = getchar()) != '\n' && response != EOF);// clear input buffer
}
return 0;
}
```

Next, I needed to create functions for the forward declaration statements in the provided code. The function that I am having problems with is here:

```
void insertFrame(Animation *pAnimation)
{
    char input[50];
    int count;
    int dupe = 0;
    int blockFrames = pAnimation->numFrames % BLOCK_SIZE;
    int blocks = (pAnimation->numFrames / BLOCK_SIZE) + 1;

    printf("Insert a frame into the Animation\n");
    scanf("%s", input);

    /* check the input to see if it matches any of the existing frames */
    for (count = 0; count < pAnimation->numFrames; count++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pAnimation->frames[count]->fileName); /*test: show the file name to be compared against*/
        if (strcmp(input, pAnimation->frames[count]->fileName) != 0)
        {
            dupe = 1;
            printf("Dupe detected!");
            return;
        }
    }

    printf("dupe = %d\n", dupe);

    /* afterwards, actually add the frame if it's ok */
    if (dupe == 0)
    {
        pAnimation->numFrames++;
        strcpy(pAnimation->frames[pAnimation->numFrames - 1]->fileName, input); /* <-- This is where the error happens */

    }
}
```

Every time I use printf or strcpy to show or modify the fileName struct member from pAnimation->frames[   ], it shows a read access violation. Upon closer inspection, it appears that the fileName from the address pointed from pAnimation->frames[   ] is unknown.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

---

Okay, so after taking the advice, this is what my initAnimation looks like:

```
void initAnimation(Animation *pAnimation)
{
    pAnimation->numFrames = 0;
    pAnimation->frames = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE * sizeof(Frame));
}
```

I have also got in contact with my professor, and he said that I didn't need to allocate anything unless I am "adding" a new frame (via insertFrame). I'm not entirely sure what he meant by that.

Comment: Why do you say `strcpy()` and `printf()` is a macro?

Comment: Your issue is probably in `initAnimation` when you're supposed to be allocating this space and setting up the arrays.

Comment: You are using the pointers as arrays. They are not the same thing, although they can be used in similar ways. You never (in this code, at least) allocate memory for the data structures you are trying to manipulate, therefore you get an access violation. On another note, this code is a pointer-nightmare. There are better ways, although this is probably just a learning exercise.

Comment: Can you reduce your example code to a smaller amount of code which still illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at

```
void initAnimation(Animation *pAnimation)
{
    pAnimation->numFrames = 0;
    pAnimation->frames = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE * sizeof(Frame));
}
```

I assume you are allocating an array of frame pointers. So each cell is `sizeof(pFrame)` not `sizeof(Frame)`. That is big enough to hold a pointer to a frame not a frame itself.

Second you need to allocate these frames as you create them.

Something like

```
pAnimation->frames[i] = malloc(sizeof(Frame));
```

Finally a `Frame` holds a Pointer to character array. You need to allocate that as well

```
pAnimation->frames[i]->fileName = malloc(50); // Use your max size
```

Also you should be checking the results of the `malloc` calls.

I would put the 2 frame allocation calls in `insertFrame()` as that is when you are creating/adding a new frame.

Comment: For some odd reason, pAnimation->frames[int].fileName produces a syntax error according to Visual Studio 2015. However, replacing the "." with the -> remedies this. It's probably because of how the professor's program works. Regardless, this has helped greatly - thanks!

Comment: Sorry my bad frames[i] is a pointer you need to use the pointer reference `->` rather than the object `.` version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change

```
pAnimation->frames = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE * sizeof(Frame));
```

to

```
pAnimation->frames = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE * sizeof(pFrame));
```

because the `pAnimation` struct member `frames` is type `ppFrames`, meaning it is a pointer to a `Frame` pointer rather than a pointer to a `Frame` (it is an array of `Frame` pointers rather than an array of `Frame`s).

I believe you also need to allocate space for each of those `Frame` pointers in the function also, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BLOCK_SIZE; ++i) {
  pAnimation->frames[i] = malloc(BLOCK_SIZE * sizeof(Frame));
}
```

Otherwise, the `Frame` pointers in the `frames` array will not point to any actual memory and you will get an access violation whenever you try to access their members.